# Android Studio disable the reflection at layout preview

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: reflection]

Im using `Android Studio 0.8.9 (BETA)`

I do not want device reflection effect at layout preview. can i turn off? like eclipse?

Comment: Which is not possible.

Comment: @Alif thanks! yes i found it! many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can Turn it off by unchecking `Show Lighting effects` on Layout Design Tab.

Am done it in Latest version of Android Studio Beta (0.9.1).

[image: Look screenshot]

Hope it helps